# How can I show $f \in L^{\infty}$ using $\sup\limits_{p \in [p_{0},\infty[}\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{p}< \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and there exists a $p_{0}$ so that $f \in \bigcap\limits_{p \in [p_{0}, \infty[}L^{p}$ and further $\sup\limits_{p \in [p_{0}, \infty[}\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{p}<\infty$.
>
> Show that $f \in L^{\infty}$.

---

Questions: Can someone explain to me why the statements $f \in \bigcap\limits_{p \in [p_{0}, \infty[}L^{p}$ and $\sup\limits_{p \in [p_{0}, \infty[}\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{p}<\infty$ are not equivalent? It most probably has something to do with the definition of $\sup$ but I do not see the difference. Further, any ideas on how I can show $f \in L^{\infty}$. I am tending towards a proof via cotradiction. So, let's assume $f \in L^{\infty}$,
it then follows that for any $\alpha> 0$ there exists an $A\in \mathcal{A}$ so that $|f(a)|>\alpha$ for all $a \in A$. And further $\mu(A) > 0$. How would this help me?

Comment: If $f =\sum nI_{(0,e^{-n})}$ then $f \in L^{p}$ for every $p$ but supremum of $\|f\|_p$ is $\infty$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? In your case I get $\int \vert \sum\limits_{n} n 1_{(0,e^{-n})} \vert^{p} d\lambda \leq \int \sum\limits_{n} (n 1_{(0,e^{-n})} )^{p} d\lambda=\sum\limits_{n} n^{p}e^{-np}$, how can I deduce $f \in L^{p}$ but $ \sup\limits_{p} \vert \vert f \vert \vert_{p}=\infty $

Comment: for the last fact I am using the fact that the p norm tends to infinity norm. Clearly the infinity norm of f is infinity.

Comment: And why is $\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{p} < \infty $ for any $ p \in [1,\infty[$

Comment: Root test or ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

If $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$, then for every $M>0$, we would have that
$$
\mu(E_M)>0,\quad\text{where $E_M=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\ge M\}$}.
$$
[Note that $\|f\|_\infty$ is the *essential supremum* of $|f(x)|$.]

Hence, for every $p\ge p_0$,
$$
\|f\|_p=\left(\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
\ge\left(\int_{E_M}|f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
\ge\left(\int_{E_M}M^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}=\mu^{1/p}(E_M)\cdot M
$$
This implies that
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\ge \lim_{p\ge p_0} \mu^{1/p}(E_M)\cdot M=M.
$$
Hence, if $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$, then we would also have that $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\infty$.